# How To Display a Random Item of a List? [Every 9 seconds]

Tags: list, flutter, random

Is there a way to display a randomQuote every 9 seconds automatically?

Below is a truncated portion of the code that matters:

```
final List<String> RandomQuotes = [ ... ] // (one hundreds quotes here)

var randomQuote = (RandomQuotes.toList()..shuffle()).first;

:

:

:

... Text(randomQuote, Style:...)
```

I've tried your suggested code, but the randomQuote var is not being used. As seen in the images below.

[image: Is the timer periodic at the right place?]

[image: randomQuote in scaffold]

[image: Error returned of Guillaume's code]

Comment: Check the Timer class: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy just use a `Timer.periodic` and define a duration of 9 seconds:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

final items = <String>['Hi', 'Hello', 'Test'];

Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 9), (_) {
  final _random = Random();
  final item = items[_random.nextInt(items.length)];
  print(item);
});
```

[Try the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/7028ce6936f31e7354171bea160c0f11?null_safety=true)

Comment: updated my code above with the results, have a look Guillaume

Comment: It is because your variable `randomQuote` is declared inside the timer and is not accessible. You need to declare `randomQuote` outside of the timer (but the timer will still assign its value) you might also want to perform a call to `setState` so your UI will be updated with the newly assigned word.

Comment: ```
 Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 9), (_) {
      setState(() {});
    });
    var randomQuote = (RandomQuotes..shuffle()).first;
```



I have changed the code to this Guillaume, the change is happening but every 9 seconds, when the quote updates, it updates twice in succession before staying on one for 9 seconds and updating twice again, I can see the jump. Even when I used your code and not the shuffle list one, it's still the same. Any idea how to stop it?

Comment: Because your timer is declared inside the build method, you should declare it inside the `initState`

Comment: right . solved it! Thanks! do you know of any way to make the old quote fade out and the new quote fade in?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution in a single line:

```
final List<String> RandomQuotes = [ ... ] // (one hundreds quotes here)

    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 9), (_) {
    var randomQuote = (RandomQuotes..shuffle()).first;

});
```

Comment: updated my code above with the results, have a look Gourango

Comment: The variable declared inside a method can't be accessed globally in a class. Please have a look at the dart programming. I hope it will solve your problem.